# How to use routeControllers in a package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My app is made of packages.
If I set up routes with iron router in one package, everything works as it should :

```
Router.route('/sessions', {
    name: 'ride_sessions.list',
    template: 'RideSessionList',
    action: function () {
         this.render();
    },
    data: function () {
        templateData = {
            rideSessions : RideSessions.find()
        }
        return templateData;
    }
});
```

But if I try to use a route Controller like this :

```
RideSessionsListController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'RideSessionList',
    action: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    data: function () {
        templateData = {
            rideSessions: RideSessions.find()
        }
        return templateData;
    }
});

Router.route('/sessions', {
    name: 'ride_sessions.list',
    controller: 'RideSessionsListController'

});
```

I get this error :

```
Error: RouteController 'RideSessionsListController' is not defined.
```

Is it a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong ?
If I'm not in a smart-package it works fine.

Comment: Maybe try `api.export`ing `RideSessionsListController` in your `package.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export all your global variables in `package.js` file:

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {

  ...

  api.export(['RideSessionsListController', ...]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I had tried this before but did'nt change anything.
I have a root package for my app calling needed sub-packages. The solution is to export in both packages (the sub-package and the root package)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a sub-package defining a global variable (e.g. `RideSessionsListController`) that needs to be bubbled up all the way to the root,

```
// sub-package/package.js
Package.describe({
  name: 'sub-package'
});

Package.onUse(function(){
  ...
  api.export('RideSessionsListController');
});

// root-package/package.js
Package.onUse(function(){
  ...
  api.imply('subpackage');
  api.export('RideSessionsListController');
});
```

You will need to `export` the global variable from the sub package, and then [`imply`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_api_imply) the sub package in the root, and re-export the previous global variable again.